# What's the number pipenv shows when installing packages?

Tags: python, pipenv

When I'm installing packages with pipenv, it says:

```
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (354967)…
  ================================ 58/58 - 00:00:07
```

What's that number? 354967? Where does it come from?

Comment: it's a lovely colour ;) https://www.colorhexa.com/354967

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the source](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/bc37beaef43de351a1a215bea1c6fad678774233/pipenv/core.py#L796-L798), it appears this is the last 6 characters of the sha256 hash of the lock file.

```
fix_utf8("Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock ({0})…".format(
    lockfile["_meta"].get("hash", {}).get("sha256")[-6:]
)),
```